# Can we be certain that the only nonzero differentiable function satisfying $g(x+y)=\frac{g(x)+g(y)}{1+g(x)g(y)}$ and $|g|\lt 1$ is $\tanh(kx)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, functional-equations, hyperbolic-functions

The following question is a question aimed for the Further Maths UK syllabus (it is a Step $2$ question)- i.e. not very formal, so I am certain my solution to the question is correct as the question intended it, but I am uncertain whether it is formally the only, or the right, solution. I am especially uncertain about my application of the Picard existence & uniqueness theorem.

The problem:

> The function $g$ has derivative $g'$ and satisfies: $$g(x+y)=\frac{g(x)+g(y)}{1+g(x)g(y)}$$For all $x$ and $y$, $|g(x)|\lt 1$ for all $x$, and $g'(0)=k\neq0$. Find $g'(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$ and $k$, and hence find $g(x)$ in terms of $x$ and $k$.

My solution (but is it unique, and is it rigorously done?):

> Consider the difference quotient for $y\neq 0$, some $x\in\Bbb R$: $$\tag{1}\frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}{y}=(1-g^2(x))\cdot\frac{g(y)}{y(1+g(x)g(y))}$$First note that $|g(x)|\lt1$ gives $(1-g^2(x))\neq0$ and $1+g(x)g(y)\neq0$. Secondly, if $g'(0)\neq0$ we must have that the numerator of the difference quotient must be nonzero in some small deleted neighbourhood of $0$ (else we could take a convergent sequence $y_n\to0$ where $g(y_n)=0$ for all $n$, and then $g'(0)=0$ if the limit exists) so if we set $x=0$, we may divide by $g(y)$ in the above with $y$ close to $0$ but $g(y)\neq0$: $$\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}=(1-g^2(0))\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{y}{g(y)}+y\cdot g(0)}$$For the above limit as $y\to0$ to exist, the limit as $y\to0$ of the denominator must exist: as $\lim_{y\to0}y\cdot g(0)$ exists (and equals $0$) we conclude $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{g(y)}$ must exist, giving: $$\begin{align}k=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}&=(1-g^2(0))\cdot\frac{1}{\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{g(y)}}\\\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(y)}{y}&=\frac{k}{(1-g^2(0))}\end{align}$$This further implies that $g(y)\to0$ as $y\to0$ and by continuity of differentiable functions $g(0)=0$, so that: $$k=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(y)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}$$Using the same argument that $g(y)\neq 0$ in some small deleted neighbourhood of $0$ and dividing by $g(y)$ in $(1)$, for now arbitrary $x$, we get: $$g'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(x+y)-g(x)}{y}=(1-g^2(x))\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g(y)}{y}=(1-g^2(x))\cdot k$$

The differential equation $g'(x)=k(1-g^2(x))$ has a solution in $g(x)=\tanh(kx)$. **I think that by the Picard existence theorem, the solution is unique** since $|g(x)|\lt 1$ gives a Lipschitz bound on $k(1-g^2(x))$, although even then we only have uniqueness potentially in some small interval around $0$. Can we really conclude $g(x)=\tanh(kx)$ with certainty? And just how necessary is the condition $|g(x)|\lt1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we can show:

> If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $f'(0)=1$, and such that for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x+y)[1+f(x)f(y)]=f(x)+f(y)$, then $f=\tanh$.

For the proof we first plug in $y=0$ to get that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $f(x)^2f(0)=f(0)$. If $f(0)\neq 0$, we have $f(x)^2=1$ for all $x$, and hence by continuity $f=1$ or $f=-1$, contradicting that $f'(0)=1$. Therefore, $f(0)=0$. Next, we have for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ that
\begin{align}
f(x+y)-f(x)&= f(x+y)-\bigg(f(x+y)[1+f(x)f(y)]-f(y)\bigg)\\
&=-f(x+y)f(x)f(y)+f(y)\\
&=f(y)[1-f(x+y)f(x)]
\end{align}
Assuming $y\neq 0$, we can now divide by $y$ and take the limit $y\to 0$, and use the fact that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ to deduce $f'(x)=1-f(x)^2$. So, $f$ is a differentiable function satisfying the ODE $f'=1-f^2$ (so by induction it is actually $C^{\infty}$) and $f(0)=0$. In the language of ODEs, if we define $\Phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as $\Phi(\xi)=1-\xi^2$, then $\Phi$ is locally Lipschitz, and $f$ satisfies $f'=\Phi\circ f$ with $f(0)=0$, i.e it is a solution of the IVP
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\xi'=\Phi(\xi)\\
\xi(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
For such (locally Lipschitz) ODEs, we have local existence and uniqueness. However, we already know a global solution exists, namely $\tanh$. Therefore, by uniqueness, $f=\tanh$.

---

Now, regarding $g$ and the assumption $g'(0)=k\neq 0$, this is easily reduced to the case $k=1$ by considering $x\mapsto g(\frac{x}{k})$.

So, your answer is essentially right, though it can be streamlined as shown above. The assumption $|g|<1$ is superfluous as shown above. More importantly, the assumption $|g|<1$ is not what's required to invoke the uniqueness results from ODEs. That theorem requires that $\Phi$ (i.e the RHS) satisfy certain regularity conditions, not that the solution you're looking for (i.e $g$) satisfy certain bounds.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for. So instead of trying to invoke Picard globally, I should have invoked Picard on a small interval where the function is Lipschitz, e.g. $[-1,1]$, obtained a unique solution there, and then argued that the global solution $\tanh$ must agree with any unique local solution hence $g(x)=\tanh(kx)$?

Comment: I don't know any ODE theory really so I assume the theorem with locally Lipschitz functions you mean is the Picard theorem - right?

Comment: @FShrike not quite. Picard only gives local existence and uniqueness. But roughly speaking, by applying the local uniqueness result in a neighborhood of every point where the solution exists, one can prove uniqueness everywhere, meaning if two functions satisfy the same ODE where the first satisfies it on an interval $I_1$ and the second on $I_2$, and if the two functions agree at one point of $I_1\cap I_2$ (assuming non-empty) then the two functions agree on all of $I_1\cap I_2$.

Comment: This is one of the first few corollaries of the local existence and uniqueness results. Hence we have a unique extension to a solution defined on the union $I_1\cup I_2$. You should perhaps gloss over an ODE text just to see the statement of the theorems to see how they're being invoked. Also, just because the function is Lipschitz on say $[-1,1]$, it doesn't mean the solution obtained is also going to be defined there... typically it's going to be a much smaller subinterval (this particular case is an exception of course since we have an explicitly defined global solution).

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\tanh(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$. Thus set $g=\frac{f-1}{f+1}$, so that $f=\frac{1+g}{1-g}$. This is non-singular everywhere due to the assumption $|g|<1$.
Then
\begin{align}
f(x+y)=\frac{1+g(x)g(y)+g(x)+g(y)}{1+g(x)g(y)-g(x)-g(y)}=f(x)f(y)
\end{align}
So $f(x)=e^{cx}$ follows for $g$ differentiable. Set $c=2k$.

Comment: Thank you - that is a nice insight. Moreover, on reflection it is *the* insight we were supposed to have, since the previous question asked us to show that any differentiable function $f$ with $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ is of the form $f=a^{kx}$ :)